# why the group $GL(6,V)$ has an open orbit?

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, mp.mathematical-physics

N.Hitchen in his paper about geometry of three forms wrote that "for a Real vector space $V$ of dimension six, the group $GL(6,V)$ has an open orbit and he referenced it to a thesis which was written in 1907 , how can we prove this fact, is there any open access reference?

Comment: This is very well explained in Hitchin's article freely available at
http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0010054v1

Comment: he only referenced it and never proved it, in which page of this paper he very well explained it?

Comment: The proof is given in section 2, pages 3 to 6, first the complex case,
then in the real case.

Comment: Is the thesis available online?

Comment: Mariano , No,I think this thesis has been written around 1930. But the proof of Robert is very nice and unique.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In any case, the proof is very simple.  Consider the $3$-form
$$
\phi_0 = dx^1\wedge dx^2\wedge dx^3 + dx^4\wedge dx^5\wedge dx^6.
$$
I claim that the subgroup $G\subset\mathrm{GL}(6,\mathbb{R})$ that stabilizes $\phi_0$ consists of the obvious subgroup $G_0=\mathrm{SL}(3,\mathbb{R})\times\mathrm{SL}(3,\mathbb{R})$ that fixes the two summands plus the discrete part that switches the two summands.  Since this subgroup has dimension $8{+}8=16$ while  $\mathrm{GL}(6,\mathbb{R})$ has dimension $36$, it follows that the $\mathrm{GL}(6,\mathbb{R})$-orbit of $\phi_0$ has dimension $20= 36-16$, which is the dimension of $\Lambda^3(\mathbb{R}^6)$.  Thus, this orbit is open.

To see the claim, just look at the vectors $v\in \mathbb{R}^6$ that satisfy $\bigl(\iota_v(\phi_0)\bigr)^2=0$.  Clearly, such a vector must lie in either the 'first' $\mathbb{R}^3$ or the 'second' $\mathbb{R}^3$.  Thus, $G$ must carry each of these subspaces into either itself or the other subspace.  The subgroup of $G$ that fixes each subspace must be of index $2$ in $G$, and is clearly $G_0$.

What is not so obvious is that there exist exactly $2$ open orbits.  One is the one listed above, and the other is 
$$
\phi_1 = \mathrm{Re}\bigl((dx^1+i\ dx^4)\wedge(dx^2+i\ dx^5)\wedge(dx^3+i\ dx^6)\bigr),
$$
whose stabilizer has an index two subgroup that is isomorphic to $\mathrm{SL}(3,\mathbb{C})$.

*Remark:*  By the way, the existence of the open orbit shouldn't be surprising.  It's a general fact that $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ has an open orbit in $\Lambda^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for $k>0$ whenever $n^2$, the dimension of $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$, is as large as $n\choose k$, the dimension of $\Lambda^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$.  This happens for all $n$ when $k\in\lbrace1,2,n{-}2,n{-}1,n\rbrace$ and otherwise only for 
$$
(n,k)\in\lbrace (6,3), (7,3), (7,4), (8,3), (8,5)\rbrace.
$$

Comment: Dear Robert, you beautifully solved it, thanks 

Comment: To see there are exactly 2 open orbits, we can use algebraic-group methods as follows. Let $G={\rm{GL}}_6$. By considering tangent spaces analytically (over $\mathbf{R}$ and $\mathbf{C}$) and algebraically (over $\mathbf{C}$), and dimensions of stabilizer groups analytically and algebraically, a point $\omega$ has open orbit under $G(\mathbf{R})$ in the analytic sense if and only if it has Zariski-open $G$-orbit in the algebraic sense (over $\mathbf{C}$, or use $\mathbf{R}$-schemes). By the nature of the Zariski topology, the open algebraic orbit through $\phi_0$ is the only one. (cont'd)

Comment: So the open orbit as an $\mathbf{R}$-variety is $G/H$ with $H = ({\rm{SL}}_3 \times {\rm{SL}}_3) \rtimes (\mathbf{Z}/(2))$. By Cor. 1 to Prop. 36 in Ch. I of Serre's "Galois cohomology" book, $G(\mathbf{R})\backslash (G/H)(\mathbf{R})$ is identified with the kernel of the map ${\rm{H}}^1(\mathbf{R},H)\rightarrow {\rm{H}}^1(\mathbf{R},G)$. The target vanishes by Hilbert 90, and the source bijects onto ${\rm{H}}^1(\mathbf{R},H/H^0)$ of size 2 since $H^0$ has only two $\mathbf{R}$-forms (itself and "${\rm{SL}}_3(\mathbf{C})$ as an $\mathbf{R}$-group") and both have trivial degree-1 cohomology.

Comment: @Hassan: If you like the answer (and you probably like it, because you have accepted it), you can also vote it up!

Comment: @kreck:  Thanks for outlining this sophisticated proof.  However, one doesn't need such tools to classify the orbits (even the non-open ones) in $\Lambda^3(\mathbb{R}^6)$, as it can be done easily using standard exterior algebra facts.  It's just not obvious (which is what I wrote).  If the reader wants details on this argument, one place they are available is in the Appendix to my article "On the geometry of almost complex $6$-manifolds" (http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0508428.pdf).

Comment: @Robert Bryant: True, I was just illustrating a method that can be used for general situations where one is trying to analyze the relationship between $G(k)$-orbits and $G$-orbits in the algebro-geometric sense (in effect, $G(\overline{k})$-orbits, for which eigenvalue issues are not too much of a headache, etc.) where $k$ can be any field of characteristic 0 (such as $\mathbf{R}$, or $\mathbf{Q}$, etc.).  For example, one might be curious about counting the number of open $G(k)$-orbits when working over other "analytic" ground fields such as $k = \mathbf{Q}_p$.

Comment: @Robert Bryant: For example, if $k = \mathbf{Q}_p$ then the number of open $G(k)$-orbits is 4 when $p$ is odd and 8 when $p = 2$, and if $k$ is a finite extension of $\mathbf{Q}_p$ then it remains 4 for odd $p$ but is a bit more complicated when $p = 2$.  

Comment: @@Dears Kreck and Robert many thanks for your helpful comments 

Comment: Dear Robert , thanks for your nice Remark